# Difference between public final void moveCamera (CameraUpdate update) and public final void animateCamera (CameraUpdate update)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

What is the difference between the methods

public final void moveCamera (CameraUpdate update) and
public final void animateCamera (CameraUpdate update)

of GoogleMap class?

When should I call getCameraPosition()?

Comment: "When should I call getCameraPosition()?" -- perhaps never. There is no requirement to call `getCameraPosition()`. The documentation is merely telling you the impacts of `moveCamera()` upon the results returned by `getCameraPosition()`, should you need it.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between those two is that:

`animateCamera` will animate the camera to the desired position with a smooth animation, while `moveCamera` will move the camera to the desired position instantly.

**Edit:**

From the docs of [CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition):

**An immutable class that aggregates all camera position parameters.**

basicly it contains all the data of the camera position like: bearing, tilt, target and zoom.

By running `getCameraPosition()` you can get this CameraPosition object.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and understanding the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) is the basic of software development.

**animateCamera(CameraUpdate update)**

```
Animates the movement of the camera from the current position to the position defined in the update.
```

**moveCamera(CameraUpdate update)**

> Repositions the camera according to the instructions defined in the
>   update.

Comment: in the documentation for moveCamera(CameraUpdate update), it is written - "...a subsequent getCameraPosition() will reflect the new position". I didn't understand what that means, please explain. Is there any requirement of calling getPosition() after calling moveCamera(CameraUpdate update)?